# Converting longitude to its $\theta$ value

Tags: geometry

If I have a longitude of say $75^{\circ} W $ , how can I convert this to $\theta$ as in polar co-ordinates. I have seen a formula that if you are travelling west then $\theta(location) = 2\pi - longitude(location) (in radians)$ . Is this correct and if so why?

To further explain my confusion.. I am thinking that the centre of the equatorial plane (the core of the Earth itself?) is $(0,0,0)$ on the $x$-$y$-$z$ plane. We measure theta counter clockwise starting from the positive x-axis. But when we derive lines of longitude, I don't know where it is located in terms of theta.

I could be making like 5 mistakes at once here folks.

Comment: If that formula is correct, all it is saying is that polar coordinates by convention measure longitudinal angles counter clockwise (when looking down from above the north pole) from 0(positive x axis/ prime meridan) raising values as we go counterclockwise/east, with pi/2(90=90 E) being the Indian ovean, pi(180) the date line and 3pi/2(270=90 W) being somewhere in south America while 2pi returns.  Longitude west goes in the opposite direction.  So x east is x, but x west is 360 - x.  Radians to degrees are just two different ways of measuring angles.  2pi = 360 degrees.

Comment: @fleablood thank you that is a great explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define what $\theta=0$ is and which direction is the positive $z$ axis.  A natural point would be the prime meridian for $\theta=0$ and $+z$ being North from the center of the earth.  Then East is increasing $\theta$, so $\theta=$ longitude.  West is decreasing $\theta$, so West longitudes are negative.  My longitude near San Francisco, CA, USA would be about $-122^\circ$.  Because of the periodicity, you could also represent my longitude as $360^\circ-122^\circ=238^\circ$.  You can use radians or degrees as you like.  Degrees are conventional, radians are more convenient for some things like trig functions.

Comment: The only thing is I am not sure what you mean by East is increasing. Can you elaborate on that.

Comment: East is increasing means Germany is at may +20 or so degrees (give are take something huge; I'm not looking at a map) and Turkey is at +60.  These are east of Greenwich.   But Spain in the west is -15 =345(or so) .  Going east means the angle is increasing positively.  Going west the angle is... well it's getting more and more negative... that's decreasing.